# Compilation error with fontspec and BoldFeatures

Tags: fontspec

Using fontspec 2.4, why won't the following example compile?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec} % version 2.4
\setmainfont[BoldFeatures={Color=AA0000}]{Arial}

\begin{document}
This is \textbf{NOT} red.
\end{document}
```

Error: `Missing \begin{document}`. It compiles with `ItalicFeatures` though.

Comment: v2.4a should already be available in CTAN to correct this. Apologies for the inconvenience.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a bug that has been fixed that should be available as corrected in an up-to-date distribution (soon).

Answer (score 1):

Apologies for the inconvenience. To answer your question: somehow an erroneous character entered into the source at a key point in the file. I'm not sure how.

v2.4a should already be available in CTAN to correct this. It might take a few days to turn up in tlmgr or the MikTeX package manager.